# Unexpected token error in for loop, why?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```js
var ccode = ['EUR', 'BRL', 'RUB', 'KRW', 'RON', 'CHF'];
  var i;
  for (var i = 0; i < ccode.length; i++) {
     var ccode[i] = fx.convert(amount, {to: 'ccode[i]'});
  }
```

The bit above `var ccode[i]` is causing an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['. Expected ';' after variable
>   declaration.

I am still new to JS so please bear with me.

I am editing my question here since people asked why I was re-declaring var ccode[i] and its because I need to output this:

```
var EUR = fx.convert(amount, {to: "EUR"});
```

Comment: why are you declaring ccode again?

Comment: `for (var i = 0;` re declares `i` again. Remove the `var`, yes and  same for `ccode`

Comment: [what does var do in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059526/what-does-var-do-in-javascript-why-is-it-sometimes-part-of-an-assignment)

Comment: I had var ccode[i] because I need to output this

"var EUR = fx.convert(amount, {to: "EUR"});"

Answer (score 1):

```
var ccode = ['EUR', 'BRL', 'RUB', 'KRW', 'RON', 'CHF'];
var i;
  for (i = 0; i < ccode.length; i++) {
     ccode[i] = fx.convert(amount, {to: 'ccode[i]'});
  }
```

ccode is already declared.. no need to use `var`

Comment: same for goes for i

Answer (score 0):

Its not about declaring `ccode` twice, as variable declaration syntax is wrong

`var ccode[i];` should not be array, see for [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

You should remove `var`.

```js
var ccode = ['EUR', 'BRL', 'RUB', 'KRW', 'RON', 'CHF'];
  var i;
  for (var i = 0; i < ccode.length; i++) {
     ccode[i] = fx.convert(amount, {to: 'ccode[i]'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an array map:

```
var ccode = ['EUR', 'BRL', 'RUB', 'KRW', 'RON', 'CHF'];
ccode = ccode.map(function(code) {
  return fx.convert(amount, {to: code})
})
```

Comment: map returns a new array, but you do not assign this result.